# Shamir Secret Sharing

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

Can anyone please explain to me why we have such equations below in part b) and c)? They are the solutions to the questions, but I can't really understand why and how to get that. Many thanks.

==== QUESTION ====

In the Shamir secret sharing scheme, we distribute a secret among q different users as
follows. If our secret is a message (m1, . . . , mk) from V (k, q) then, we encode it as a codeword of the Reed-Solomon RSk(q) and give one coordinate to each user. In this
problem, we will use q = 7, k = 4 and the parity check matrix H4 below for RS4(7).
H4 =
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1,
0 1 2 3 4 5 6,
0 1 4 2 2 4 1]

a) Write a generator matrix for RS4(7)

b) A new secret is selected and user #1 receives share value 0, user #2 receives share
value 6 and user #3 receives share value 1 and are collaborating to discover the
new secret. Explain why they can’t recover the secret with only this information.

c) Now, suppose users #1, #2 and #3 (as in the previous item) discover, in addition
to the values of their own shares, that users #4 and #5 have identical shares (but
they don’t necessarily know what the common value is). Using this information,
first explain how they can collaborate to recover the secret and then find the
secret.

====ANSWER====

a.  The generator matrix is:
H3 =
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1,
0 1 2 3 4 5 6,
0 1 4 2 2 4 1,
0 1 1 6 1 6 6]

I totally get (a), just put it here for context.

b) If the secret is (x1, x2, x3, x4), the given conditions produce the equations:
x1 = 0,
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 6,
x1 + 2x2 + 4x3 + x4 = 1
and there are many solutions to this equation, as you can choose e.g. x2 arbitrarily
and solve for x1, x3, x4.

c) In addition to the equations
x1 = 0,
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 6,
x1 + 2x2 + 4x3 + x4 = 1
from the previous item, we also have the equation
x1 + 3x2 + 2x3 + 6x4 = x1 + 4x2 + 2x3 + x4
which gets simplified to
x2 + 2x4 = 0
and now we have 4 equations in 4 unknowns and we can check they have full
rank and solve it to get that the secret is (0, 4, 4, 5).

Comment: This question would be a far better fit on crypto.SE instead of math.SE.  I suggest that you ask the Moderators to _migrate_ this question to crypto.SE which has lots of questions and answers already on Shamir secret sharing.  You can contact the Moderators by clicking on the `Flag` link below your question.